# Can tinnitus be measured with EEG or MEG?

Tags: neuroscience, perception, clinical-psychology, neuroimaging, eeg

- Can [tinnitus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinnitus) be measured with EEG or MEG (magnetoencephalography)?
- Is it visible in a power spectrum?
- In an ERP/ERF?

Comment: I think I've created a MEG tag, but as @ArtemKaznatcheev found, there are broader tags to use for your question. I found 8 questions involving MEG, but mostly through the answers. Yours is one of the first few questions that pertains directly to MEG.

Answer (score 6):

[Michelle Heijblom's (2009) master thesis on Visualising tinnitus with fMRI and EEG](https://www.mst.nl/neurochirurgie/Onderzoek/tinnitus/) mentions the following:

> Different studies report that tinnitus is characterised by an increase
>   in slow-wave activity (0.5- 4Hz: delta activity) and a decrease in
>   alpha activity (8-12 Hz) at temporal regions. Recently it has been
>   suggested that this loss of alpha power is related to an increase in
>   gamma power. [Weisz 2005, Weisz 2007, Lorenz 2009, Ashton 2007,
>   Wienbruch 2006]. Weisz et al. state that the alpha decrease and delta
>   increase resemble the state during slow wave sleep. This supports the
>   idea that the changes in spontaneous brain activity might be mediated
>   by sensory deprivation (hearing loss).

Comment: Interesting answer (+1).  I am going to have to do some reading on this subject.